# How to pass serialized parameter to query in Refit

Tags: c#, serialization, query-string, refit

I try to send GET request to API, I need to create url like

```
test.com/api.php?apitoken=1111&event_name=buy_year&event_data={"ubtcuid":"ckerggrggsg1ini","event_datetime":"2021-07-02 15:36:40","client_id":"123456"}
```

My C# code:

```
[Get("/api.php")]
Task<Response> SendAsync([Query][AliasAs("apitoken")] string apiToken,
            [Query][AliasAs("event_name")] string eventName,
            [Query][AliasAs("event_data")] EventData eventData);
```

```
public class EventData
{
    [AliasAs("ubtcuid")]
    public string UbtcUid { get; set; }
        
    [AliasAs("event_datetime")]
    public DateTime EventDatetime { get; set; }
        
    [AliasAs("client_id")]
    public string ClientId { get; set; }       
}
```

And Refit build URI like:

```
test.com/api.php?apitoken=1111&event_name=buy_year&ubtcuid=ckt112kh0&event_datetime="2021-07-02 15:36:40"&client_id=123456
```